# Return duplicates in a table AND attached non duplicate column

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I'm trying to search a table and find any instances of a duplicate in one of the columns, i would also like to return the value of another column which will not be duplicated.

For instance my table could look like

```
ctrl_nbr   curr_code
001        999
002        888
003        777
004        999
```

I can't seem to get my code to return both the ctrl_nbr and curr_code values together.

Here's what i have so far:-

```
select curr_code from ctrl_hdr
where nbr_sfx = 'A'
group by curr_code
having count(ctrl_nbr) > '1'
```

This correctly gives me curr_codes that have duplicate ctrl_nbr but if i add the ctrl_nbr to the select and the group functions then nothing is returned.

I've also tried:-

```
SELECT ctrl_nbr,
   curr_code
FROM ctrl_hdr
WHERE curr_code IN
 (SELECT curr_code
  FROM ctrl_hdr
  WHERE nbr_sfx = 'A'
  GROUP BY curr_code 
  HAVING count(ctrl_nbr) > '1')
```

But this just seems to enter some sort of loop and doesn't end.

Comment: You have no dublictates in combination of both values. So it is corect that you get no result.

Comment: Can you paste the desired results for the sample data you posted?

Comment: For the off the top of my head example i've put in the question i would expect ctrl_nbrs 001 + 004 to be returned as they have the same curr_code (999).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ctrl_nbr,
       curr_code
FROM ctrl_hdr
WHERE curr_code IN
    (SELECT curr_code
     FROM ctrl_hdr
     WHERE nbr_sfx = 'A'
     GROUP BY curr_code HAVING count(ctrl_nbr) > 1)
```

Comment: Sorry i will update my question, i did try this as well and it seems to enter a loop with no end.

Comment: count(ctrl_nbr) return int value not string..you must write Count(ctrl_nbr)>1

Comment: no problem...i think your query must work..as it works for me too

Comment: I'm beginning to think that it's a performance issue - trying what @bulat anwsered with below has given me the same unending procssing. Any kind of join using the curr_code seems to just hang. Thank you for your anwser though.

Comment: That may be true. Does your subquery alone return? If so, you can limit your subquery to 1 (or a few) row(s) and see if you get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

There are three scenarios I can think of.

First, you want to find duplicate records and show both in a single row:

```
SELECT c1.ctrl_nbr, c2.ctrl_nbr,  c1.curr_code 
FROM 
  ctrl_hdr c1 INNER JOIN 
  ctrl_hdr c2 ON c1.ctrl_nbr < c2.ctrl_nbr AND c1.curr_code = c2.curr_code
```

Second, you want to select the last/first duplicate:

```
 SELECT c.ctrl_nbr, c.curr_code 
 FROM     ctrl_hdr c 
   WHERE EXISTS ( -- it is a duplicate
         SELECT * FROM ctrl_hdr  
         WHERE c.curr_code = curr_code AND c.ctrl_nbr != c2.ctrl_nbr)
   AND NOT EXISTS ( -- it is the last dupicate
         SELECT * FROM ctrl_hdr  
         WHERE c.curr_code = curr_code AND c.ctrl_nbr < ctrl_nbr)
```

And last, you want to get all the duplicate records except first / last:

```
 SELECT c.ctrl_nbr, c.curr_code 
 FROM     ctrl_hdr c 
 WHERE EXISTS ( -- it is non-last duplicate
         SELECT * FROM ctrl_hdr  
         WHERE c.curr_code = curr_code AND c.ctrl_nbr < ctrl_nbr)
```

Comment: I omitted  `WHERE nbr_sfx = 'A'` as not relevant to the question.